# What is the difference between a neutrino and an antineutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, neutrinos, elementary-particles

Since an antiparticle by definition is a particle with the same mass but opposite charge, how is there such a thing as an antineutrino? A neutrino has 0 charge so could not have an opposite. So why does an antineutrino exist and how does it differ from a neutrino?

Comment: "an antiparticle by definition is a particle with the same mass but opposite charge" - That's not the *definition* of an antiparticle; that's just two properties that antiparticles happen to have.

Comment: It does seem to be utterly identical to that other question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This is the table of elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#/media/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) of the standard model of physics.

[image]

There exists the symmetric *anti particle* table, where the quantum numbers are such that added, particle + antiparticle the sum is zero.

The neutrinos carry the lepton number of the corresponding lepton, the antineutrinos the negative .

In addition neutrinos and antineutrinos, react to first order with the weak interaction only, are distinguished by chirality:

> For each [neutrino,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Antineutrinos) there also exists a corresponding antiparticle, called an antineutrino, which also has no electric charge and half-integer spin. They are distinguished from the neutrinos by having opposite signs of lepton number and [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)). As of 2016, no evidence has been found for any other difference

The chirality difference, the way the spin of a fermion  is oriented with respect to its motion, gives different i[nteraction crossections](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-nu-cross-sections.pdf); for example neutrino nucleon scattering versus antineutrino nucleon scattering.

Comment: What does a lepton number represent?

Comment: In the table there are three lepton numbers, electron, muon and tau. The represent the  number of leptons, the way baryon number represents the number of nucleons.  It is the reason that neutron( beta) decay goes into an e- and and antineutrino e and a proton, a three body decay instead of just a proton and an electron. Lepton number would beviolated otherwise. That is how the existence of neutrinos was established.

Comment: @Charlie It has been found that some quantities are conserved.  What they represent is ... some quantity that is conserved.  Interactions ... conserve those quantities.  The product after and before ... remains the same.  Some of them also impact how they interact in various interactions in ways that are not obviously related to the conservation of their number.

Comment: I thought it is still not proven that neutrino isn't its own antiparticle. Is it settled now?

Comment: Wait isn't Z its own antiparticle?

Comment: @VladimirF: It was, and then somebody noticed they can't be chiral if they're massive (which they are). That is, a left handed neutrino has a vantage point at which it appears right handed. Nobody knows how to fix the theory yet and the own-antipartical has a cult following again.

Comment: @VladimirF from the chirality link "The resolution to this false paradox is that the chirality operator is equivalent to helicity for massless fields only, for which helicity is not frame-dependent. By contrast, for massive particles, chirality is not the same as helicity, so there is no frame dependence of the weak interaction: a particle that couples the weak force in one frame, does so in every frame."  semantics, and a mathematical definition of chirality with gamma matrices

Comment: @Joshua  bosons can be their own antiparticle , as the Z, if  zero charge

Comment: @annav But from the same chirality link: "After the observation of neutrino oscillations, which imply that neutrinos are massive like all other fermions, the revised theories of the electroweak interaction now include both right- and left-handed neutrinos." That seems to be in disagreement with your answer.

Comment: @VladimirF  Not really, just the way they interact changes , the operator does not change. They are just massive fermions as far as chirality goes,

Answer (score 12):

> A neutrino has 0 charge so could not have an opposite

A (left-handed) neutrino has zero *electric* charge $Q$ but it is not uncharged.

The neutrino (anti-neutrino) has [weak isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) charge $T_3$ of +1/2 (-1/2) and [weak hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge) $Y_W$ of -1 (+1).

The relationship of these three charges is given by

$$Q = T_3 + \frac{Y_W}{2}$$

and so, the neutrino is electrically neutral but not uncharged.

Comment: My physics is not that advanced; could you explain what isospin charge is and what causes it and also explain hypercharge?

Comment: @Charlie, in my answer, I linked to the appropriate Wikipedia articles.  Explaining what these charges are would best be done in a separate question and answer.

Comment: Cheers :) I'll research it