# Vacuum Cherenkov Radiation

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, neutrinos, cherenkov-radiation

Hi I was reading this paper (Pair Creation Constrains Superluminal Neutrino Propagation) for an assignment and I came across the following question:
in the article, it is said that if we assume that Neutrinos are superluminal then they would undergo Cherenkov-like processes even in vacuum as they would be kinematically allowed. However, neutrinos are fully neutral particles so they should not undergo Cherenkov-like radiation right?
Could someone explain?

Comment: Neutrinos have weak hypercharge. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/338938/123208

Answer (score 4):

Neutrinos have no *electric* charge, and thus should not undergo Cherenkov radiation. They have other charges,  weak hypercharge and weak isospin. The "Cherenkov-like" radiation the paper proposes would have weak bosons taking the place of photons.